# Testcontainers performance slower than plain docker

Tags: liquibase, testcontainers, liquibase-maven-plugin

I have the following scripted out and it works, but it was suggested that I try using testcontainers.

```
function die { mvn docker:stop ; exit 1; }

function initializeDatabase {
   docker exec -it mysql-1 mysql -uroot -proot \
   -e "DROP USER IF EXISTS 'myuser'@'%';" \
   -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;" \
   -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" \
   -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';" \
   -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%';"
}

mvn docker:start && sleep 10

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution1 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution2 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution3 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution4 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution5 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution6 || die

mvn docker:stop
```

The above takes about 6 minutes to run.  It starts a docker container running mysql and initializes the database and runs some liquibase migrations against it 6 different times, mimicking 6 different environments.  It takes a little over 6 minutes to run.  From Java, using testcontainers and the liquibase java API, it takes over 10 minutes to run.  Any thoughts on how I can improve the performance of my testcontainers implementation?  I don't think it's liquibase because it's the same liquibase code being invoked behind the scenes.

Below is my code:

```
import liquibase.Liquibase;
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection;
import liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException;
import liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.SearchPathResourceAccessor;
import org.junit.*;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SimpleMySQLTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static MySQLContainer<?> mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:latest"))
            .withEnv("TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLED", "true")
            .withEnv("TESTCONTAINERS_CHECKS_DISABLE", "true")
            .withEnv("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", "root")
            .withEnv("MYSQL_ROOT_HOST", "%")
            .withDatabaseName("root")
            .withUsername("root")
            .withPassword("root");

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        mysql.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        mysql.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void NAMSDev() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl().replace("/root", "/rms"), "rms", "rms")) {
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/sql/baseline/mysql/NAMSDev/databaseChangeLog.master.xml", new SearchPathResourceAccessor(".", new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), new JdbcConnection(connection));
            liquibase.update("NAMS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    @Before
    public void initializeDatabase() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl(), "root", "root")) {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("DROP USER IF EXISTS 'rms'@'%';");
            statement.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS rms;");
            statement.execute("CREATE DATABASE rms;");
            statement.execute("CREATE USER 'rms'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'rms';");
            statement.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON rms.* TO 'rms'@'%';");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void NAMSQc() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl().replace("/root", "/rms"), "rms", "rms")) {
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/sql/baseline/mysql/NAMSQc/databaseChangeLog.master.xml", new SearchPathResourceAccessor(".", new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), new JdbcConnection(connection));
            liquibase.update("NAMS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void NAMSProd() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl().replace("/root", "/rms"), "rms", "rms")) {
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/sql/baseline/mysql/NAMSProd/databaseChangeLog.master.xml", new SearchPathResourceAccessor(".", new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), new JdbcConnection(connection));
            liquibase.update("NAMS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void NORDICSDev() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl().replace("/root", "/rms"), "rms", "rms")) {
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/sql/baseline/mysql/NORDICSDev/databaseChangeLog.master.xml", new SearchPathResourceAccessor(".", new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), new JdbcConnection(connection));
            liquibase.update("NORDICS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void NORDICSQc() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl().replace("/root", "/rms"), "rms", "rms")) {
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/sql/baseline/mysql/NORDICSQc/databaseChangeLog.master.xml", new SearchPathResourceAccessor(".", new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), new JdbcConnection(connection));
            liquibase.update("NORDICS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void NORDICSProd() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysql.getJdbcUrl().replace("/root", "/rms"), "rms", "rms")) {
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/sql/baseline/mysql/NORDICSProd/databaseChangeLog.master.xml", new SearchPathResourceAccessor(".", new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), new JdbcConnection(connection));
            liquibase.update("NORDICS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a github repository and share the code of both? Something you can do is split the tests and run in parallel. JFTR, here is the link for reuse container docs https://www.testcontainers.org/features/reuse/

Comment: If you're using Linux, you could try doing `.withTmpFs(Map.of("/var/lib/mysql", "rw"))` on the `MySQLContainer` in order to store data in memory instead of on the file system.